# CSS line-height attribute

Tags: attributes, css

Could someone please explain the CSS line-height attribute. It's like the only one I don't know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The name is self-explanatory; defines the height of a line of text. This is one CSS property that's easier to show than to explain:

---

[image]

---

Look at my example here if you want to see the CSS and a working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/G59VX/.

Comment: Yes, that's what it does. If you are interested in best practices then use whole numbers rather than pixel values to set it. More here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/line-height

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Didn't know about the numeric heights.

Answer (score 1):

It sets the height of a text line independent of the `font-size`.  If you increase it, the lines will appear to be moving further apart, vertically.

Answer (score 1):

The line-height is just that, it adjusts the full hight of a line of text, irregardless of font size. A healthy line height gives a paragraph of text a little breathing room and can make it much easier on the eyes. I usually do a line-height of 1.25em give or take.

[image: example of line-height]

Answer (score 0):

Line-height defines the **amount of space used for lines**, most commonly in text. The primary use of line-height is **making text readable**. It is recommended to use unitless values of any other unit that isn’t static like the px unit.

A more detailed use is explained [here](https://kolosek.com/css-line-height/).